# -bash: gcc: command not found - Mavericks

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I have installed

- Xcode 5
- Command line tools
- gcc with homebrew

But when I try to use gcc command it says:

```
-bash: gcc: command not found
```

The location

```
gcc -version -bash: gcc: command not found 
bolo:~ Michelin$ ls /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc-4.
```

http://cl.ly/image/3m2U1N0q1B2l

update

```
bolo:~ Michelin$ xcode-select -p
Usage: xcode-select -print-path
   or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
   or: xcode-select -version
Arguments:
   -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
   -switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
   -version                        Prints xcode-select version information
bolo:~ Michelin$ xcode-select -print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

and

```
bolo:~ Michelin$ locate */bin/gcc
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/gcc
bolo:~ Michelin$
```

update (12:18pm)

on my system

```
bolo:~ Michelin$ ls /usr/local/bin/gc
gcc-4.2   gcov-4.2
```

My bash_profile

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

and after.

```
bolo:~ Michelin$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Michelin/.rvm/bin
```

Thanks

Comment: Xcode 5 uses clang, not gcc.

Comment: Ok I have install gcc with hombrew however I have still a command not found

bolo:~ Michelin$ gcc -version
-bash: gcc: command not found
bolo:~ Michelin$ ls /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 
/usr/bin/gcc-4.

Comment: If the command isn't found but you know it exists on your system, you need to modify your shell's PATH environment variable to include the directory that contains it. I'm not sure what you're trying to convey with your `ls` command -- what are its results?

Comment: What do `xcode-select -p` and `locate '*/bin/gcc'` show?

Comment: @Kevin please see my update in original message. tks

Comment: on my system the `gcc` at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcccommand` appears to actually be clang, so maybe that is your problem?

Comment: Not sure why Xcode didn't copy gcc to /usr/bin like it did on my system, but if you add either of the paths shown by the `locate` command to your `PATH` you'll be able to use it. The homebrew installation isn't showing, if you just installed it the db may not have updated. Check that it's in /usr/local/bin and add that to your path.

Comment: @BradAllred that's true but not the problem.

Comment: @kevin  add my response in my orignal message. tks

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the question - post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok probleme solved. I have replaced my bin folder by other one and now every works.

Answer (score 0):

Maverick is not came with .bash_profile. Need to change bash_profile using vim or nano command.

Edit with following...

```
# Set architecture flags
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
# Ensure user-installed binaries take precedence
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
# Load .bashrc if it exists
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```